# How to create .aar file with library source code?

Tags: android, gradle, aar

I have a library with all the source files inside of it. I need to compile this library into an *.aar* file, but I can't seem to import it into a module or project. There is no *.idea* folder within this library.

How can I create an *.aar* file out of this?

Answer (score -1):

If the library is in your project with the source, then it is already compiled each time you run. Look under `<your_lib>` -> `build` -> `outputs` -> `aar`. There you will have an .aar for each build type you have. i.e. debug and release

Answer (score -1):

It may be simplest to create a new AAR library module in Android Studio and then copy the source and resources for your library into the new module. To do this select **File > New > New Module... > Android Library**.

However, if you already have an Android project and you just want to alter the build to generate the project as an AAR library rather than an application, you can change the plugin used in the Gradle build script.

Alter the apply plugin line from:

```
apply plugin: ‘com.android.application’
```

to:

```
apply plugin: ‘com.android.library’
```